# Question about spherical capacitor

Tags: electric-fields, capacitance, gauss-law

I was trying to find the capacitance of a spherical capacitor using : $$C=\frac{Q}{V}=\frac{Q}{E(R_2-R_1)}=\frac{Q}{k\frac{Q}{(R_2-R_1)^2}(R_2-R1)}=\frac{R_2-R_1}{k}$$ where R1 is the radius of the inner sphere and R2 the radius of the outer sphere.

From what I found online what I do gives a wrong result. I know how I can get the right one by integrating to find voltage but my question **what is wrong with the way I tried solving it**.

One guess is that I can't use $$E=\frac{V}{d}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Capacitance is given by $\frac{Q}{\Delta V}$.

$$\Delta V = \frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \int_a^b{\frac{1}{r^2}dr}$$

$E$ is given by $-\frac{dV}{dr}$ (for all cases), your form is valid only for constant $E$, with uniform direction. (disregarding the sign).

Comment: As I said I know how to find the capacitance. I just don't know what is wrong with the way I tried solving it.

Comment: Added that to the answer!